# How to check a null sql date in java

Tags: java

I am developing a hospital management system for an assignment.I want to view patient details and display "not discharged" if the column date_of_discharge is null.I'm using mysql as database.Do I want to convert sql date to java util date before checking it null?

Comment: No, the conversion is useless. If it is not null it remains not null no matter conversion you make, because not null means the reference points to something instead of nothing (null case).

Comment: Instead of checking not null,can I directly check whether it is null?

Comment: Of course ......

Answer (score 3):

## NULL is nothing

> Do I want to convert … before checking it null?

No.

As others commented, NULL means “nothing at all”. A NULL is the same across all data types. So no need to convert, cast, or parse when simply asking if the value is NULL or not.

> Instead of checking not null,can I directly check whether it is null

Yes. Use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM patient WHERE date_of_discharge IS NULL ;
```

…or…

```sql
SELECT * FROM patient WHERE date_of_discharge IS NOT NULL ;
```

## Avoid NULLs

> display "not discharged" if the column date_of_discharge is null.

Following [Dr. Chris Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date)’s [advice](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1682377.A_Guide_to_the_SQL_Standard), I avoid using NULL wherever possible, as if it were the work of the devil (which it may be!).

Instead, assign a certain value of your own arbitrary choosing to signify *no-value-yet-assigned*. Perhaps the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) date of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and other systems: the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

In Java, we have available as pre-defined constants: [`LocalDate.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

## Never cast between `java.util.Date` & `java.sql.Date`

> convert sql date to java util date before checking it null

No, never cast between these types. You should ignore the fact that [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) inherits from [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). By inheriting, the `java.sql.Date` actually carries a time-of-day. Yet `java.sql.Date` portrays itself as representing a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone — but this is only a pretense. As a workaround, to fulfill that pretense, that time-of-day is set to midnight of some time zone. But the `java.util.Date` always represents a moment in UTC. So by casting, you will inadvertently be mixing in the effect of some time zone.

Confusing? Yes. This is a *terribly* bad design, an awful hack, and is one of *many* reasons to **avoid these old legacy date-time classes**. Use *java.time* classes instead.

## JDBC 4.2

As of [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Use `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` methods.

The `java.sql.Date` class that pretends to hold a date-only value is supplanted by the `java.time.LocalDate`. The `LocalDate` class actually does hold only a date, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

…and…

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.It works.And through this answer l learnt new things.Again thank you for the answer.